# JS: Append elements recursively inside of each other

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

can I append a list of elements inside of each other infinitely using JS Vanilla?
For example:

```
let list = ["div","ul","li", "a"...]
```

results:

```
<div>
 <ul>
   <li>
    <a>...</a>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure; show your initial attempt and describe what's not going well and we can jump in to help from there.

Comment: I'm trying to create a function that I give it a string like this 
```
"div//ul//li//a//..."
```
and it should return the result that I told before and this is my first attempt I have not got the logic yet :/ 
```
    function createEl(str){
        let list = str?.split('//'),
        frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

        for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            x= document.createElement(list[i])
            x.append(document.createElement(list[i+1]));
            frag.append(x); 
            break;
        }
        return frag;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We create element from the first item, then append to it the rest, using recursion on the now list minus first item.

```js
let list = ["div", "ul", "li", "a"]

function list_to_elements(list) {
  if (list.length == 0) {
    return null;
  }
  var first = document.createElement(list.shift());
  var rest = list_to_elements(list);
  if (rest) {
    first.appendChild(rest);
  }  
  return first;
}


var result = list_to_elements(list)
console.log(result.outerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body id="body">
</body>
<script>
    let list = ['div','ul','li','a'];
    for(var i = 0 ; i<4 ; i++)
    {
        var element = (list[i]);
         document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += 
         ("<"+element+"></"+element+">");
    }
</script>
</html>

This code will create this kind of structure
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) array methods as follows - in memory - and then append the result to whatever DOM element it needs to be appended to.

```js
const list = ["div","ul","li", "a"],
      theHTML = list.reverse().reduce(
          (acc,el) => `<${el}>${acc}</${el}>`,
      "...");
      //"..." can be replaced with whatever content should be enclosed in the last element
      
      console.log( theHTML );
```